# SSIS task Data Flow - Converting flat time value HHMMSS to MSSql Time(7) field

Tags: ssis, etl, dataflow

I am creating an SSIS task that imports a tab del Flat File into a SQL table. I have been successful with all fields except the time field. The time field is stored in the FLAT file as HHMMSS. How do I convert this to the Time(7) data type? I've tried the Data Conversion function within the Data Flow and have failed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "ETL" file? Is it SSIS?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Used a "Script Component" and used VBA to convert the data type.